# C++ vs Java: Arrays of Objects

Tags: java, c++

**C++:**

```
Student* sp = new Student[10];
```

Now, please correct me if wrong. I believe this creates an array of 10 instances of Student, each calling the default constructor with no arguments.Please use arrays and not vectors.

**Java:**

```
Student [] sa = new Student[10];
```

Again, correct me if I'm wrong but I think in case of Java though, no instances are created when this statement executes and instead only memory is reserved to hold 10 references to Student instances.
And it is necessary that we follow it up with:

```
sa[0] = new Student(*arguments*);
sa[1] = new Student(*arguments*);
.
.
.

sa[9] = new Student(*arguments*);
```

I'm trying to see the difference and quite frankly, I'm confused. Kindly clarify please.

Comment: You can't easily do that in C++. Using a vector is the answer (this becomes trivial), so it's a little pointless outright disallowing it.

Comment: I know but I'm trying to understand the concept of ARRAYS of Objects here. I may use Vectors but I want to have Arrays in my repertoire as well.

Comment: Can you see the difference I'm trying to highlight. In C++ they are instantiated whereas in Java, they are not. Is my understanding correct or am I horribly mistaken here?

Comment: Well, it's actually better C++ to not use any dynamic allocation, unless there's good reason.

Comment: Even though everyone will kill kittens if you use arrays in C++, there's nothing wrong with trying to understand how they work in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You're trying to see the difference, but you already described the difference fairly accurately.

Comment: Does std::array is your requirement? [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/)

Comment: Java's array is more like this in C++: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Student>>`. C++ array and Java array are called the same but they're not the same. That's why people tell you to use vectors instead.

Answer (score 10):

What do you mean, you're trying to see the difference and you're confused? The difference is exactly what you've stated. The C++ code creates an array of 10 `Student` objects that are default-initialized [1], and the Java code creates an array of 10 references so no `Student` constructors are called until you do it yourself.

Maybe your question is *why* C++ and Java differ. That's because a `Student[]` in Java is an array of `Student` references, so the true C++ equivalent would be an array of `Student` pointers,

```
Student** sp = new Student*[10]
```

which you would indeed have to follow up with

```
sp[0] = new Student(args);
...
sp[9] = new Student(args);
```

analogously to your Java example.

Now, if you want an array of 10 `Student` objects in C++ initialized using a constructor other than a default constructor, you have to do it in two steps: first allocate memory for 10 `Student` objects, then manually construct the `Student` objects over that memory using placement `new`. **I do not endorse this style of coding. It is very confusing even to experienced C++ programmers.**

```
typedef Student SA[10]; // SA means array of 10 Students
SA* psa = static_cast<SA*>(::operator new(sizeof(SA)));
SA& sa = *psa; // sa refers to an array of 10 Students
new (&sa[0]) Student(args); // construct the Student object
// ...
new (&sa[9]) Student(args);
// later
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sa[i].~Student(); // destroy the Student object
}
::operator delete(psa); // deallocate the memory for the array
```

Use a damn vector.

[1] Note: In C++, for a class, *default-initialized* means that the default constructor is called; for an array, it means each element is default-initialized; and for an arithmetic, pointer, reference, or enum type, it means it's not initialized at all.

Comment: btw, I have made several edits to the answer because I screwed it up the first few times. Tricky stuff. Better to just use vectors.

Comment: Please add a clarification what *default-initialized* means. Especially, that it need not be the same as calling the default-constructor. And for your last example, we have brace-and-init-initializers, which are better.

Comment: You should a clarification what a scalar type means as well.

Comment: Your first line of code is incorrect - did you mean: Student **sp = new Student*[10] ?

Answer (score 6):

#### Short answer:

Those two declarations are different. The C++ one allocates an array of `Student` objects, while the Java one allocates an array of **references** to `Student` objects.

#### Long answer:

The difference is that, in Java when you declare an object:

```
Student s;
```

It creates a reference (similar to a pointer in C++) to a `Student` and initializes the reference to `null`. You can then later assign a `Student` object to that reference variable with `s = new Student()`.

But in C++ when you declare an object:

```
Student s;
```

It creates an actual object (not a reference to an object as in Java). And thus the object must be immediately instantiated.

---

So in Java, when you do this:

```
Student [] sa = new Student[10];
```

It actually creates an array of *references* to `Student` objects (not an array of actual `Student` objects), and they are all initalized to `null` references.

> ...I think in case of Java though, no instances are created when this statement executes and instead only memory is reserved to hold 10 references to Student instances.

So yes, you're right.

But in C++ this:

```
Student* sp = new Student[10];
```

dynamically allocates an array of actual `Student` objects. Again, not references as in Java, so each object will be instantiated immediately.

> I believe this creates an array of 10 instances of Student, each calling the default constructor with no arguments.

Correct as well.

So in Java after declaring the array of references you can then instantiate the actual objects and assign them to those references in the array with this:

```
sa[0] = new Student(*arguments*);
```

But in C++ the `Student` objects in the array were already instantiated, so this is not needed.

---

#### Bonus: Array of *pointers* in C++

In C++, you can also declare an array of pointers to postpone object instantiation, similar to the Java array of references:

```
Student** spp = new Student*[10];
```

This will create an array of 10 *pointers* to `Student` objects. You can then instantiate the objects when needed and assign their memory addresses to the pointers:

```
spp[0] = new Student(*arguments*);
```

This looks a lot like Java, but is actually not generally recommended in C++. In fact, using `new` in C++ should be avoided most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a round about way of accomplishing what you are hoping to using the `new` operator.

```
#include <new>

struct Student
{
   Student(int ){}
};


int main()
{
   // Allocate memory for 10 Students.
   // Don't construct Student objects yet.
   char* cp = new char[10*sizeof(Student)];

   // Now construct the Student objects using
   // placement new
   Student* sp[10];
   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      sp[i] = new (cp + sizeof(Student)*i) Student(10);
   }

   // Use the Student objects
   // ...
   // ...

   // Call the destructor on the Students explicitly.
   for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      sp[i]->~Student();
   }

   // Deallocate the memory.
   delete [] cp;
}
```